# wp_insert_term in a multisite installation

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, terms

i am creating a theme that creates pages and sets some meta values and ext on theme activation. Everything works great but...

I need to insert some terms to misc cpt's in a multisite installation.

**i tried this method:**

```
switch_to_blog($blog_id);
wp_insert_term($move_type, 'jobtype');
restore_current_blog();
```

**does not work. Ideas anyone?**
Even a DB method would be great if you got one.

Comment: Your code is working but problem is unlike plugins theme can not be activated network wide. So if you even inserted terms using SQL, What does it make sense when theme is not activated on that blog and does not even display that taxonomy? Better you move this code to plugin.

Comment: thanks for taking an intrest ;) first comment. the theme would always be active. users has no access to the admin part. I just want to make the "activation" process a one click job. i dont want to use any plugin and it would not matter - this code doesnt work - wp_insert_term always tries to insert into the main / top blog... using an SQL command i could integrate the blog id (which i get correcrtly) i just dont know how to write that command. that being said - i would rather use a "wordpressy" solution, but.. any solution would do.

Comment: Okay! But an admin will activate the theme at least once on every site? Because when you create a new site a default theme is activated. An admin need to activate the custom theme on a new site.
Most important thing your code is working, I've tested ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are activating theme on Network but here I am considering a case of installing fresh theme on a existing Network.

Activating theme on any single site will insert the term for every site in Network but yes of course taxonomy registration code should be there already.

Consider this example

```
function after_switch_theme_callback() {
    $blogs = wp_get_sites(); //Array of site Ids
    foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
        if (!empty($blog['blog_id'])) {
            switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']);
            wp_insert_term('myTerm '.$blog['blog_id'], 'genre');
            restore_current_blog();
        }
    }
}
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'after_switch_theme_callback');
```

It seems to me working fine.

**Note:**

> Register your taxonomy on `init` action so later terms can be inserted
>   on `after_switch_theme` action.

Comment: hmm... i need only the current blog - but.. will try it. i didnt think about the timing of stuff and thus a hook might do the trick. Will get back to you soon and thanks again ;)